# Combining Multiple LINQ Queries as OR statements in each query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Each user can belong to 1 to 5 different clubs. For each club the user belongs to, I want to add that as or statement in my query but I am not sure how to do that. Here is what i have so far:

```
var userClubs = GetUserClubs(currentUserName); // List<string>

foreach (var c in userClubs)
{
      query = query.Where(t => t.Club == c);
}
```

This is the statement I am looking for:

```
query = query.Where(t => t.Club == c[0] ||  t.Club == c[1] || t.Club == c[2].....c[x]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
query = query.Where(t => userClubs.Contains(t.Club));
```

Comment: It depends what's the type of `userClubs`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I believe it is `List<string>`. Op's commented code makes me to think like that.

Comment: It said List<string> next to the variable as a comment. So mine will work?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I doubt it.  I'd expect any type that's a valid column for an Entity to be supported here.  Were this LINQ to objects then perhaps not, but it isn't.

Comment: @Servy What if it's a navigation property?

Comment: @jls No, you're still in the game. +1

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I liked the predicate builder. That will come in handy in the future.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I'm reasonably confident that would still work.